# Использование `number_format` на Twig

Tags: twig

Как конвертировать запятые в точку, например имеется счет: **1,973.85** хочу конвертировать так: **1973.85** и умножит на `2`, делаю следующее:

```
{{ 1,973.85|number_format(2, ',', '.') * 2 }}
```

Но получаю ошибку. На выходе нужно получить такой формат: **3 947.7**

Как это реализовать на **Twig**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала нужно произвести умножение, а потом выполнять форматирование. То есть вот так:

```
{{ (1973.85 * 2)|number_format(2, '.', ' ') }}
```

Ссылка на документацию: [`number_format`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html). Функция принимает один, два или три аргумента. Чуть больше информации с GitHub по данной функции: [Add number_format filter](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/commit/0edcfdd). Аргументы функции:

- `decimal` - количество десятичных точек для отображения
- `decimal_point` - символ, который следует использовать для десятичной точки
- `thousand_sep` - символ, используемый для разделителя тысяч

Примечания:

- Наличие скобок у операции умножения - обязательно, иначе будет ошибка
- Число, которое умножается на 2 - должно быть правильного формата (быть числом)

Если ваше начальное число `1,973.85` - это уже отформатированная строка с разделителем тысяч в качестве запятой - необходимо удалить запятую и все возможноые проблелы из строки и затем привести строку к числу. Приведу пример:

```
{{ ('1,973.85'|replace({',' : '', ' ': ''}) * 2)|number_format(2, '.', ' ') }}
```

Изначально есть строка `'1,973.85'`, с помощью `replace` мы удаляем из нее запятые и пробелы. Затем умножаем полученное значение на два, так как мы умножаем на число, приводить строку к типу данных числа нет необходимости, а далее как и в предыдущем примере - просто задаем формат вывода.